# Find first occurrence each year with a criterion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the following dataset, I would like to find the date of occurrence of 1, if 1 repeats for at least for (say) 3 days in a row, (and if 1 happens less than 3 days, it just ignores)

```
date    strat
2006-01-01  0
2006-01-02  1
2006-01-03  1
2006-01-04  1
2006-01-05  0
2006-01-06  1
2006-01-07  0
…   
2059-12-27  0
2059-12-28  1
2059-12-29  1
2059-12-30  1
2059-12-31  0
```

What would be the most practical way?

Comment: `if 1 repeats for at least for 3 days, I get the first occurrence day`. So what do you want if 1 repeats for < 3 days in a year?

Comment: if 1 repeats for < 3 days in a year, I just want to skip those days and go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. You extract the year from your date series. Then filter for years where strat sum is greater than equal to 3. Finally, sort values by date and drop duplicates by year.

```
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year

res = df.loc[df.groupby('year')['strat'].transform('sum') >= 3]\
        .sort_values('date')\
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['year'])

print(res)

         date  strat  year
6  2006-12-26      1  2006
```

**Setup**

Modified to demonstrate the logic you wish to apply:

```
print(df)

          date  strat
0   2005-12-24      0
1   2005-12-25      0
2   2005-12-25      1
3   2005-12-25      0
4   2005-12-25      1
5   2005-12-26      0
6   2006-12-26      1
7   2006-12-26      1
8   2006-12-26      1
9   2006-12-27      1
10  2006-12-27      0
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp, but one problem here is that it works fine for the first year, but from the next year it only lists the first day of each year, not the day that the criterion applies. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Behnam, Sorry, I'm not sure what you're looking for. Can you update your question demonstrating how the above solution doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my question @jpp. Now I have only one value for each day. I think it is now clearer

Comment: @Behnam, The "3 days *in a row*" criterion is completely new to me. You may have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the df where strat equals 1

```
df = df[df.strat == 1]
```

Drop duplicates lines in your df (if you have more columns and you whant, you can whrite subset=['date', 'strat'])

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=True)
```